# Another domain is pointing to my server, and Google is indexing that one rather than mine

Tags: apache-2.4, abuse

So I own `www.example.com`.
I have an A record pointing to my IP, and also have a CNAME for `www.`

Clearly my IP is shared, because if I access it, I get taken to `www.domain.com`

Anyway, last week, I googled for `www.example.com`, and it's been indexed under `www.domain.com` which is pointing to my IP. I assume some type of nasty SEO scrapping site?

This led me to this post on the [webmaster exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72689/block-a-random-domain-pointing-at-my-dedicated-ip/72694#72694), where I implemented the Perl script shown. Now, when I google my domain, the blackhat one still shows up, even though if you click on it, the page shows a 404 like this: [404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ77m.png).

This site has now been responding with a 404 when accessed, yet it's still indexed instead of my real website. How can I actually stop google from indexing this website, and I guess, further block it? My VHosts and .htaccess is pretty simple.

Comment: What happens if you visit domain.com rather than www.domain.com?  Does your site load? Where does domain.com point to? You cannot have a cname at the root level.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtualhost for your domain. Send all other traffic to another directory on your web server containing an `index.html` file.

Then, in that `index.html`, include a `noindex` meta tag in the page's HTML code. When Googlebot next crawls that page and see the tag or header, Googlebot will drop that page entirely from Google Search results, regardless of whether other sites link to it.

Then, use Google's [URL Inspection Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289) to reset the search results for both domains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask Google to re-crawl your website. Sadly it can take up time.

> C**rawling can take anywhere from a few days to a few weeks.** Be patient
>   and monitor progress using either the Index Status report or the URL
>   Inspection tool.

Please see that link for submission to a re-crawl; https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en